# Preseeding in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, preseed

Can Ubuntu 20.04 still be preseeded the d-i style?

As far as I understand it's not supported anymore.
But is it still doable?

Edit: this is about the server installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit**: as rightly pointed out by *user535733*, my information below pertains to the server installer.  I'm less familiar with the desktop installer.

The debian-installer (d-i) **server** images are still available and have been renamed *legacy*.  For 20.04 they are available at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-legacy-server/releases/20.04/release/

Preseed still works with these images.

In the server discourse threads it has been indicated that 20.04 is the last release that will generate the d-i images
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/c/server/l/latest

Comment: You might wish to clarify that this is for the server installer (subiquity)  only. The desktop installer (ubiquity) is unchanged and future releases can still be preseeded.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some background information about why sometimes debian-installer may be preferred over subiquity.